# creating a variable to hold information that loads through another variable

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Hard to explain in the title but my question is this:
I am using leaflet to create a map. Some information will be very repetitive, so I want to create variables to hold that information. I'm having trouble making the variables connect to eachother properly though to display properly. Is this possible? see code below to see what I mean. All the code works fine if I input the individual data for the variables (the lat/lng) I'm just not sure how to call the data from the somePlace variable into the food variable.

Example:

```
    var somePlace = [{
    "name": "name",
    "address":"address"
    "lat": "",
    "lng": "",
    }];

    var anotherPlace = [{
    "name": "name",
    "address":"address"
    "lat": "",
    "lng": "",
    }];

    var food = [
    {
    "name": name.somePlace,
    "address": address.somePlace,
    "lat": lat.somePlace,
    "lng": lng.somePlace,
    "details": "info unique to this object"
    },{
    "name": name.anotherPlace,
    "address": address.anotherPlace,
    "lat": lat.anotherPlace,
    "lng": lng.anotherPlace,
    "details": "info unique to this object"
    }
    ];
```

then in the main JS, this data is called in like so.

```
    for (var i = 0; i < somePlace.length; ++i) {

  var place = somePlace[i].details;

  var sP = L.marker([somePlace[i].lat, somePlace[i].lng], {
      icon: myIcon
    })
    .bindPopup(place);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a misconception in your code. Looks like you want the `food` variable to contain information from `somePlace` and `anotherPlace`.

`somePlace` and `anotherPlace` are *arrays* of *objects* which means that you can access their elements via an index such as `somePlace[i]` where `i` is an integer (as described in the loop you've pasted).

When you get an *object* from the array, (eg. the first object with `var myElement = somePlace[0]`, because arrays in JavaScript are zero indexed), you can then access the object's *properties* via what is called dot notation.

So in your example, if you want to use the first element of the `somePlace` array and the first element of the `anotherPlace` array to form the `food` variable, you can do something like:

```
var food = [{
    "name": somePlace[0].name,
    "address": somePlace[0].address,
    "lat": somePlace[0].lat,
    "lng": somePlace[0].lng,
    "details": "info unique to this variable"
    },{
    "name": anotherPlace[0].name,
    "address": anotherPlace[0].address,
    "lat": anotherPlace[0].lat,
    "lng": anotherPlace[0].lng,
    "details": "info unique to this variable"
}];
```

The objects are in key - value pairs, so for example in the case of eg. `var foo = { name: "Mary" }`, `name` acts as the `key`, `Mary` as the value and `foo` is the variable declaration, in this case an object.

Answer (score 0):

If you expect repetitive structure, one way to solve this would be through the use of constructors.

```
// constructor
function Place(name, address, lat, lng, detail) {
  this.name = name;
  this.address = address;
  this.lat = lat;
  this.lng = lng;
  this.detail = detail;
}

// declare empty array
var food = [];

// instance of Place
var somePlace = new Place('The Greatest Place', '1234 Main St', '45', '-17', 'Unique detail');

food.push(somePlace);

// another instance
var anotherPlace = new Place('Another Place', '777 High St', '47', '-18', 'Another unique detail'); 

food.push(anotherPlace);

// objects stored in your array
console.log(food);

// access specific object and property
console.log(food[0].name);
```